# Questions on hooking up an old cathode ray tube (CRT)

Tags: cathode-ray-oscilloscope

I bought an **8LO29I** Soviet era CRT (intended for use in oscilloscope/instrumentation):

[image: CRT]

Now I'd like to get it to work. After almost endless reading up (I'm not an electrical engineer) I think I now know what to do. The CRT also came with extensive original documentation (in Russian, dare I mention it!), so that helped a lot.

The function of the pins is explained as:

> Electrode leads:
>
> - 1, 14 - heater
> - 2 - cathode
> - 3 - modulator
> - 5 - the first anode
> - 7 - signal deflecting plate Y 1
> - 8 - signal deflecting plate Y 2
> - 9 - second anode
> - 10 - temporary deflecting plate X 1
> - 11 - time deflecting plate X 2
> - 4, 12 - connected.

**Pin schematic:**

[image: Pin schematic]

For my use the deflection plates will not be needed.

What I still don't get is what the modulator (pin 3) is supposed to do and whether I need one. Some searching came up [with this](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1715201?journalCode=rsi):

> An electronic system is described for modulating the beam intensity of a cathode‐ray oscilloscope in such a manner as to reduce variations in trace brightness due to differences in writing speed. A voltage derived by a push‐pull differentiating amplifier from the vertical deflection signal is added to the instrument's intensity‐control voltage. By use of this system, improved photographs of wave forms canbe obtained.

So is that what it's supposed to be, an intensity modulator?

Second question:

All these smallish CRTs seem to have 2 anodes, why is that? In one publication I read it described the second anode as the *focusing anode*. Is that correct?

Comment: Just very, very curious: what you are going to do without the deflection plates?

Comment: @fraxinus I want to run an *electron diffraction* experiment. The beam will be pointed at a piece of ultrathin gold leaf, which will be inserted just behind A2 (with a hack, obviously).

Comment: Ah, I understand. Please, pretty please, get us some results!

Comment: @fraxinus Yes but it will take time. Patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks similar to US tubes like 3JP1 that I have fiddled with ages ago. There is a control grid to change the brightness of the spot. It might have to be -50V relative to the cathode to extinguish the spot (the higher the anodes and focus electrode voltages the more negative the grid voltage will have to be).

Normally you'd used it to blank the retrace on an oscilloscope, for example. If you were trying to display a picture you'd also modulate the brightness during each scan line.

If you power it up at nominal voltages and currents you'll burn the phosphor if you don't deflect the spot or dim it. It's intended to be scanned.

On the illustrated type of CRT, there's a high voltage 3rd anode (maybe there is a connector on the side of the tube) that is fed a constant voltage in the kV range, a relatively high voltage 2nd anode (also fed a constant voltage), and a lower voltage first anode (hundreds of V) that you adjust in order to focus the spot. It should be 20-35% of the 2nd anode voltage in this particular case.

See the linked datasheet.

[image]

---

[Yours](https://frank.pocnet.net/sheets/084/8/8LO29I.pdf) does not seem to have a separate 3rd anode so more designed for slower scan speeds and probably more deflection sensitivity. 1500V constant on A2, adjustable 280-516V on A1 for focus. -67.5 to -22.5V to blank the spot. Heater is 6.3V.

Comment: I forgot to add the pin schematic, I've now added it.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a third anode, nor a connector on the side of the tube. Does that mean that on my CRT the 2nd anode is the  focusing anode?

Comment: A1 is for focus.

Comment: Thanks for the addition (and the download but I already had it). Answer accepted.

Answer (score 3):

**Intensity Modulator**

The brightness of the dot or beam on the face of the CRT depends on how many electrons impinge on that spot.  The more electrons, the brighter the spot.

Assume that the number of electrons coming from the cathode & making their way to the face of the CRT is constant.  Then if the beam were stationary, you would see a very bright spot at one location of the face.  This may actually cause damage to the CRT by "burning" the phosphor coating.

So then if you move the beam, the number of electrons hitting the face of the CRT at any point in time is reduced, which means a lower brightness.  The faster the beam moves, the fewer electrons hitting any point on the face and so the dimmer the spot/trace.

The purpose of the intensity modulator is to prevent this from happening, by reducing the number of electrons coming off the cathode as the beam moves slower.  And this is done by controlling the voltage on the cathode.

Answer (score 0):

1+14 are the heating filament. Scope tubes usually need around 6.3V, preferrably AC, and consume anywhere from 0.25A to 2A.

2 is the cathode. The potential difference between the cathode and the filament should be as low as possible. Sometimes the cathode is connected to one of the filament pins.

3 is the brightness control grid, also called the Wehnelt cylinder and usually marked as G1. It should always be more negative than the cathode, otherwise the tube might be damaged. More negative voltage results in lower brightness. Set it to 0..-50V with respect to the cathode with a potentiometer.

9 is, I assume, the anode. It should be at the same potential as the deflection plates, and at least a few hundreds volts more positive than the cathode. Some tubes require 1-2kV for good results, low voltage ones work from ~400V up.

5 is either for focus or astigmatism control. Some tubes have both of them and even further electrodes. It's usually a few hundred volts more positive than the cathode. Control with a potentiometer connected between the anode and cathode.

10 is not clear, it might be the "slot" separating the horizontal and vertical deflecting plates. It's there mostly for decoupling, and should be on the same potential as the plates.

Some tubes feature a second acceleration stage, also called post-deflection acceleration (PDA). That can be up to 10kV in modern, high performance tubes. They would work even with PDA=anode 1, but with very reduced brightness.